# Networkx VS graph-tool

Tags: python, performance, comparative-review, graph

I'm working on graph mining, so I'm trying to find the best library to do that.
I've read in [here](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/performance) that "graph-tool" is faster, so I tried the same program who count the duplicated graphs (I call them frequent in the program) in networkx and graph-tool.

The graph are in this .txt file:

> ```
> t # 0
> v 0 0
> v 1 3
> v 2 9
> e 2 1 68
> e 0 1 10
> e 0 2 4
> t # 1
> v 0 2
> v 1 11
> v 2 6
> v 3 10
> v 4 18
> v 5 14
> e 0 1 15
> e 2 5 19
> e 1 3 20
> t # 2
> v 0 6
> v 1 11
> e 0 1 13
> t # 3
> v 0 2
> v 1 11
> v 2 19
> v 3 2
> e 0 1 15
> e 1 2 11
> e 0 3 19
> t # 4
> v 0 1
> v 1 16
> v 2 14
> e 0 1 8
> e 1 2 5
> e 0 2 19
> ```

Networkx program:

```
import networkx as nx 
from networkx.algorithms import isomorphism
#from collections import Counter
import time
ti=time.time()
# read graphs from file.
def readGraphFile(graphFile):
    G_list = []
    indice = []
    frequence_list = []
    frequentgraphs = []
    frequentfreqs=[]

    appearance = [] #store the appearance of the frequent pattern
    fp = open(graphFile, "r+")
    lines = [line for line in fp.read().splitlines() if line]
    for line in lines:
        data = line.split()
        if data[0] == 't':
            if (len(data) < 3):
                print 'Graph header line error...'
            else:
                g = nx.Graph()
                G_list.append(g)
                indice.append(data[2])
                #G_list[ map(int, data[4:])] = g


        elif data[0] == 'v':
            data = line.split()
            if (len(data) < 3):
                print 'Node data line error...'
            else:
                g.add_node(data[1], attrib = data[2])
                #as node graph transaction format is single value, use attrib as a common noun for all attrib
        elif data[0] == 'e':
            if (len(data) < 4):
                print 'Edge data line error...'
            else:
                g.add_edge(data[1], data[2])
        else:
            print line
            print '!!! Invalid graph data line...!!!'
    graphdic = dict(zip(G_list, indice))

    #print(graphdic)  

    print '= = = = = Finished reading {} graphs from the file'.format(len(G_list)) + '= = = = ='
    #print 'Total graphs in list: ', 
####Frequency Algorithm #####
    ta=time.time()    
    i=0
    cnt=0
    #inc=0;    
    for gr in G_list:


        for c in G_list: 
                if (nx.is_isomorphic(gr,c)): cnt+= 1
                #if (isomorphism.GraphMatcher(gr,c).subgraph_is_isomorphic):inc+= 1


        print ("graph:{} frequence:{} ".format(i,cnt))
        frequence_list.append(cnt)
        cnt=0
        i+= 1
        print("-----------------------")


    freqdic = dict(zip(G_list,frequence_list))
    print("\n=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=")
    #try: seuil=float(raw_input('Entrer un Sieul:'))
    #except ValueError: print ("float")
    for gr, fr in freqdic.iteritems():
        if fr >= 2: 
            frequentgraphs.append(gr)
            frequentfreqs.append(fr)

    frequentgraphsdic= dict(zip(frequentgraphs,frequentfreqs))
    print("\n=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=\n frequent items:{}\n".format(len(frequentgraphs)))
    #print(frequentgraphsdic)

    print("* * * * * D O N E * * * * * ")    
    print("RUNNING TIME: {}s".format(time.time()-ti))    
    print("Reading from file: {}s".format(ta-ti))    
    print("Algo: {}s".format(time.time()-ta))    

#############################    





#programme pricipale    
def  main():
    readGraphFile("5.txt")

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Graph-tool program:

```
#import networkx as nx 
#from networkx.algorithms import isomorphism
from graph_tool.all import *
import graph_tool.all as gt
#from collections import Counter
import time
ti=time.time()
# read graphs from file.
def readGraphFile(graphFile):
    G_list = []
    indice = []
    v_indice = []
    e_indice=[]
    frequence_list = []
    frequentgraphs = []
    frequentfreqs=[]
    #appearance = [] #store the appearance of the frequent pattern
    fp = open(graphFile, "r+")
    lines = [line for line in fp.read().splitlines() if line]
    for line in lines:
        data = line.split()
        if data[0] == 't':
            vdic={}
            vdic.clear()
            if (len(data) < 3):
                print("Graph header line error...")
            else:
                g = Graph()
                v_label = g.new_vertex_property("int")              
                v_num = g.new_vertex_property("int")
                e_label = g.new_edge_property("int")
                G_list.append(g)
                indice.append(int(data[2]))
                #G_list[ map(int, data[4:])] = g

        elif data[0] == 'v':
            data = line.split()            
            if (len(data) < 3):
                print 'Node data line error...'
            else:
                #g.add_node(data[1], attrib = data[2])
                v=g.add_vertex()
                v_num[v]= int(data[1])               
                v_label[v] = int(data[2])
                vdic[int(data[1])]=int(data[2])
                #as node graph transaction format is single value, use attrib as a common noun for all attrib
        elif data[0] == 'e':            
            if (len(data) < 4):
                print 'Edge data line error...'
            else:
                #print(vdic)
                v1=g.add_vertex()               
                #vdic[int(data[1])]
                v_label[v1] = vdic[int(data[1])]                
                v2=g.add_vertex()
                v_label[v2] = vdic[int(data[2])]
                e1 = g.add_edge(v1,v2)
                e_label[e1]=int(data[3])               

        #else:
            #print line
            #print '!!! Invalid graph data line...!!!'
    graphdic = dict(zip(G_list, indice))

    #print(graphdic)  

    print '= = = = = Finished reading {} graphs from the file'.format(len(G_list)) + '= = = = ='

####Frequency Algorithm #####
    ta=time.time()    
    i=0
    cnt=0
    #inc=0;    

    for gr in G_list:                
        for c in G_list:
            if (gt.isomorphism(gr,c)): 
                cnt+= 1                            
                print("iso")
        print ("graph:{} frequence:{} ".format(i,cnt))        
        frequence_list.append(cnt)
        cnt=0
        i+= 1
        print("-----------------------")


    freqdic = dict(zip(G_list,frequence_list))
    print("\n=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=")
    #try: seuil=float(raw_input('Entrer un Sieul:'))
    #except ValueError: print ("float")
    for gr, fr in freqdic.iteritems():
        if fr >= 2: 
            frequentgraphs.append(gr)
            frequentfreqs.append(fr)

    frequentgraphsdic= dict(zip(frequentgraphs,frequentfreqs))
    print("\n=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=x=\n frequent items:{}\n".format(len(frequentgraphs)))
    #print(frequentgraphsdic)

    print("* * * * * D O N E * * * * * ")    
    print("RUNNING TIME: {}s".format(time.time()-ti))    
    print("Reading from file: {}s".format(ta-ti))    
    print("Algo: {}s".format(time.time()-ta))    

#############################    





#programme pricipale    
def  main():
    readGraphFile("5.txt")

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Results:

> ```
> Networkx >>> RUNNING TIME>>> 0.00204300880432s
> graph-tool>>>RUNNING TIME>>> 0.0780489444733s
> ```

I'm not sure if my graph-tool program needs amelioration or if that is the best performance.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  It would be helpful if you'd add a problem statement that explains what the code is supposed to do.  I.e. something more specific than "graph mining".  What's the output supposed to be?  Why?

Comment: The program count the duplicated graphs (I call them frequents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing to the terminal is slow, and I notice the second version has a `print` call in an inner loop where the first version has not:

```
    for c in G_list:
        if (gt.isomorphism(gr,c)): 
            cnt+= 1                            
            print("iso")
```

For more accurate timings

- Remove all `print` calls from the code you want to time
- Use the `timeit` module and let it repeat the timings to reduce the impact of random effects.

Comment: Even without `print` Networkx still faster than graph-tool, I dont know why because graph-tool is based on c++ boost library.